# Define external App action in AndroidManifest.xml, Master & Child Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have quite a few Activity extending a parent Activity called `MasterActivity`, which centralizes all common functions being used in child activities, including a side menu. I would like to launch an App that has a custom action given:

> com.example.otherapp.action.CUSTOMACTION

Here is the `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<activity android:name=".MasterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.otherapp.action.CUSTOMACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In `MasterActivity.java` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.otherapp.action.CUSTOMACTION");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

When I navigate to one of its child Activity in App, it shows Exception:

> No Activity found to handle Intent

and crashed. However, when I added the following entry into `AndroidManifest.xml`, it will launch an action selector:

```
<activity android:name=".ChildActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.otherapp.action.CUSTOMACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have a hundred of activities, it is not practical to add a lot `intent-filter` in the manifest. What are the alternatives?

---

Also, how can I launch the App **directly**, without choosing from action selector? I would like to launch the App like this:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.otherapp");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

but the above way cannot set the action.